# Python can't find module in site-packages

Tags: python, django, pip, package

I am trying to use PayPal's rest sdk, and in its api.py file, one of the modules it is trying to import is requests, but it is throwing a "no module name 'requests' error". I recently switched from using Python2.7 in my projects to Python3.5. I installed requests with pip-3.5 install requests, and I can see that requests in now in my python3.5 site-packages directory, but it is still throwing an error ? It is not throwing an error for other modules in the same directory like 'logging', and 'json', only requests. below is a tree structure starting at my lib directory. I tried to clean it up as much as possible.

tree python3.5/site-packages/

```
├── README
├── __pycache__
│   ├── easy_install.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
│   └── easy_install.cpython-35.pyc
├── easy_install.py
├── pip
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── __main__.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
│   │   ├── __main__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── basecommand.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
│   │   ├── basecommand.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── baseparser.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
│   │   ├── baseparser.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── cmdoptions.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
│   │   ├── cmdoptions.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── download.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
│   │   ├── download.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── exceptions.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
│   │   ├── exceptions.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── index.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
│   │   ├── index.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── locations.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
│   │   ├── locations.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── pep425tags.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
│   │   ├── pep425tags.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── status_codes.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
│   │   ├── status_codes.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── wheel.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc
│   │   └── wheel.cpython-35.pyc
├── requests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── adapters.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── api.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── auth.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── certs.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── compat.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── cookies.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── exceptions.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── hooks.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── sessions.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── status_codes.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── structures.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── utils.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── adapters.py
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── auth.py
│   ├── cacert.pem
│   ├── certs.py
│   ├── compat.py
│   ├── cookies.py
│   ├── exceptions.py
│   ├── hooks.py
│   ├── models.py
```

myprojectroot/third_party/paypalrestsdk/api.py ( imports )

from **future** import division

```
import base64
import datetime
import requests
import json
import logging
import os
import platform
import ssl

import paypalrestsdk.util as util
from paypalrestsdk import exceptions
from paypalrestsdk.config import __version__, __endpoint_map__
```

Stack Trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1531, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 938, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Django_Projects/creek_kooler/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/virt_python_35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/timothybaney/virt_python_35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/timothybaney/virt_python_35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/virt_python_35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/timothybaney/virt_python_35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Django_Projects/creek_kooler/settings/development.py", line 3, in <module>
    from third_party import paypalrestsdk
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Django_Projects/creek_kooler/third_party/paypalrestsdk/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from paypalrestsdk.api import Api, set_config, configure
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Django_Projects/creek_kooler/third_party/paypalrestsdk/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from paypalrestsdk.api import Api, set_config, configure
  File "/Users/timothybaney/Django_Projects/creek_kooler/third_party/paypalrestsdk/api.py", line 5, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

Comment: have you tried to import requests directly from the python prompt?

Comment: Yes, in the python3.5 shell I 'import requests' with no errors.

Comment: and from Pycharm too?

Comment: Well I managed to fix it by going into my virtual environment and pip installing requests there. I would of though that since my virtual environment is using python3.5, that it would of picked up any site-packages from python3.5 ?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea. But that's good if you fixed it.

Comment: Thats alright, thank you anyway Jean-Francois : )

Comment: @TimothyJosephBaney It should. Check your PATH and PYTHONPATH

Comment: A long time ago when you created virtual environments the Python module search path would chain off the ``site-packages`` for the Python you were running when creating the virtual environment. This is no longer done any more as it is a bad idea for various reasons. You now need to install all packages into the virtual environment, even if they already exist in the system wide Python.